# Cannot consume messages from beginning when put consume.on('message,callback) inside another callback

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I push messages from kafka consumer to mongodb.

- If I put the `MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {})` inside callback of `consumer.on('message', callback)`, the consumer is able to get messages from beginning.

Example code:

```
consumer.on('message', (message) => {
    MongoDB.connectDB((err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        const db = MongoDB.getDB();
        const collectionKafka = db.collection('transaction');
        try {
            insertMessage(message, collectionKafka);  
        } catch (e) {
            throw e
        }
    })
});
```

- However, if I put the `consumer.on('message', callback)` inside `MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {})`, then the consumer not get messages from beginning.

With this code, the consumer only consume latest messages, it is not able to consume from beginning. How to fix this problem

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const assert = require('assert');

const { Consumer, Offset, KafkaClient } = kafka;
const { MongoClient } = mongo;

const topic = 'testprocessing';

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'test_kafka_processing';
let mongodb;

const client = new KafkaClient({kafkaHost: 'localhost:9092'});

const topics = [{
    topic: 'testprocessing',
    offset: 0,
    partition: 0
}];

const options = {
    autoCommit: false,
    fetchMaxWaitMs: 1000,
    fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024,
    fromOffset: true
};

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    mongodb = client.db(dbName);

    consumer.on('message', (message) => {
        const collection = mongodb.collection('transaction');
        // Insert some documents
        let msg = JSON.parse(message.value);
        collection.insertOne(msg,
            function(err, result) {
                assert.equal(err, null);
                console.log("Inserted message into the collection");
                //callback(result);
        });
    });

    consumer.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('error', err);
    });
});

const consumer = new Consumer(client, topics, options);
```

---

Even if I put the initial `consumer` inside callback of `MongoClient.connect`. Consumer doesn't still fetch messages

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const assert = require('assert');

const { Consumer, Offset, KafkaClient } = kafka;
const { MongoClient } = mongo;

const topic = 'testprocessing';

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'test_kafka_processing';
let mongodb;

const client = new KafkaClient({kafkaHost: 'localhost:9092'});

const topics = [{
    topic: 'testprocessing',
    offset: 0,
    partition: 0
}];

const options = {
    autoCommit: false,
    fetchMaxWaitMs: 1000,
    fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024,
    fromOffset: true
};

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    mongodb = client.db(dbName);
    const consumer = new Consumer(client, topics, options); // <== put the initial of consumer at this time
    consumer.on('message', (message) => {
        const collection = mongodb.collection('transaction');
        // Insert some documents
        let msg = JSON.parse(message.value);
        collection.insertOne(msg,
            function(err, result) {
                assert.equal(err, null);
                console.log("Inserted message into the collection");
                //callback(result);
        });
    });

    consumer.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('error', err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Consumer is not initialized in "paused" mode. Consequently, the consumer will start fetching Kafka messages before the MongoDB connection has been established, even before the `.on('message')` handler has been set up.

The fix is to set the `paused` option flag in the consumer's option object.

[Link to the lib code line](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/blob/51b6292340b12af423c1e331ab5eda0f3beb1852/lib/consumer.js#L41)

```
const options = {
    autoCommit: false,
    fetchMaxWaitMs: 1000,
    fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024,
    fromOffset: true,
    paused: true // <-- "start the consumer paused"
};

const consumer = new Consumer(client, topics, options);

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    mongodb = client.db(dbName);

    consumer.on('message', (message) => {
        const collection = mongodb.collection('transaction');
        // Insert some documents
        let msg = JSON.parse(message.value);
        collection.insertOne(msg,
            function(err, result) {
                assert.equal(err, null);
                console.log("Inserted message into the collection");
                //callback(result);
        });
    });

    consumer.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('error', err);
    });

    consumer.resume() // <-- the consumer starts processing kafka messages after a MongoDB connection has been established
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I just have one question: even if I put the initialization of consumer  `const consumer = new Consumer(client, topics, options);` inside callback of `MongoClient.connect` (I don't use your option for this try). The consumer doesn't still fetch data.Why?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - please append an example snippet to your question, or open a new question.

Comment: Sorry Jorgenkg. Please ignore my question. I misunderstood your answer and the consumer source code.